# How to select specific row by foreign key?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two table:

```
class symbol(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='stock')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='USD')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class daily_price(models.Model):
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(symbol)
    price_date = models.DateTimeField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_updated_date = models.DateTimeField()
    open_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    high_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    low_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    adj_close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    volume = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I want to select table strategyceleryapp_daily_price's rows.

I want to use read_sql_query to select specific row by `symbol's ticker`(foreign key)

```
con = sqlite3.connect("/home/leo/github/StrategyCeleryWebsite/db.sqlite3")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from strategyceleryapp_daily_price", con)

# verify that result of SQL query is stored in the dataframe
print(df.head())

con.close()
```

In django, I can use `daily_price.objects.get(symbol__ticker='AAPL')`.

But I don't know how to write the command from sql command.

How should I write this command?

Thank you very much.

Comment: why you use `sqlite3.connect`? did you know Django bassed on **_ORM (Object-relational mapping)_**?

Comment: Yes, I know ORM. But this code runs by pure python. thanks.

Comment: how about this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: In django, I can use daily_price.objects.get(symbol__ticker='AAPL').But I don't know how to write the command from sql command.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL, you join tables and check for value:

```
SELECT dp.* from strategyceleryapp_daily_price dp INNER JOIN strategyceleryapp_symbol s on dp.symbod_id=s.id where s.ticker='AAPL'
```

You can check a query that django create with:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

and then:

```
print(daily_price.objects.get(symbol__ticker='AAPL').query)
```

Comment: you will getting traceback `AttributeError: 'daily_price' object has no attribute 'query'`, `.query` only available for queryset, not for `.get()`. an example `daily_price.objects.filter(symbol__ticker='AAPL').query.__str__()`